# `tabulate` order columns by keys

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to print my list output in a different column order. I use `tabulate` but could use other tools. The strings have different length and part of the problem is to "automatically" define the column length, which tabulate does really well!

**Code:**

```
parameter_list = []
parameter_list.append({
    'A': "Hello",
    'B': "You",
    'C': False
})
parameter_list.append({
    'A': "Salue",
    'B': "Tu",
    'C': False
})

print tabulate(parameter_list, headers='keys')
```

**Output - IS:**

```
A     B   C
----- --- -----
Hello You False
Salue Tu  False
```

**Output - WANT:**

```
C     A     B
----- ----- ---
False Hello You
False Salue Tu
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is Because you are `dict` are unordered. You can use [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) from the [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#module-collections) module.

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> from tabulate import tabulate
>>> parameter_list = []
>>> parameter_list.append(OrderedDict([('C', False), ('A', 'Hello'), ('B', 'you')]))
>>> parameter_list.append(OrderedDict([('C', False), ('A', 'Salue'), ('B', 'Tu')]))
>>> print tabulate(parameter_list, headers='keys')
  C  A      B
---  -----  ---
  0  Hello  you
  0  Salue  Tu
```

Comment: Can I also order my existing dict using OrderDict?

Comment: Yes you can using `OrderedDict(sorted(your_dict.items(), key=<optional>))`